# How to add leiningen to existing clojure projects

Tags: maven, emacs, clojure, leiningen

I'm pretty new to clojure development and I'm trying to work on some existing projects in emacs. The problem is, none of them have a project.clj file and I can't get an proper repl going. When I `cider-jack-in`, I get a working repl, but when I try to run any commands `(C-c C-k/C-x C-e/etc)` I get an error saying `Could not locate lang__init.class or lang.clj on classpath`. Are there any resources about how to make a clojure maven project to work with a lein repl?

Thanks.

EDIT: Additionally the project I'm working on is a nested project with multiple sub-projects with their own pom.xml. Any help on how such projects should be laid our to work with leiningen?

Comment: You can start an [`nrepl`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl) using Maven and connect from Emacs with `cider-connect`. Or maybe you can can convert a Maven project's `pom.xml` to a Leiningen `project.clj` with https://github.com/thickey/lein-nevam.

Comment: I did try maven nrepl with `cider-connect`, but for some reason it tells me that I don't have the correct version for `cider-nrepl`, which I can't figure out how to fix, and I can't compile/execute/etc and also I can't use the `M-./M-,` for symbol lookup.

Comment: You might need to change the version of `cider-nrepl` in your `~/.lein/profiles.clj`.

Comment: Tried that. Changed it to the latest available but doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try a similar approach with Clojure Boot, a interesting alternative to Leiningen. Someone has made a `with-pom` task for Boot: https://libraries.io/github/cpmcdaniel/boot-with-pom.

Among the cool things about the Boot repl is their classloader allows you to dynamically add dependencies to the session jvm via (set-env!) without restart.

Comment: The link seems to be broken. I will look into boot but I'd still like to know how to change this into a leiningen project though.